# C# Unit Test - Test return method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

Trying to get a basic understanding of unit testing. I've created a model class that contains a method that returns a "Person" object. Now i want to test if this method "GetPerson" is actually returning a Person object (P1).

Following the pattern of "Arrange, Act, Assert iv'e intanciated the Person class. I just don't know how to proceed from here. Would appreciate some help.

Person Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(int id, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    Person p1 = new Person(1, "John", "Dhoe");

    public Person GetPerson()
    {
        return p1;
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetPersonTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            Person p = new Person(1, "John", "Dhoe");


            //Act



            //Assert


        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a test for that. Compiler ensures that it is indeed a `Person`.

Comment: Am pretty sure you can't even run this code. Doesn't that result in `StackoverflowException`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel OP's `GetPerson` method might be a static method. It seems more suitable for that.

Comment: @BartoszKP Then you might be using something else, not OP's exact code.

Comment: @ssg As you guess it might be. To OP: It might be better to post real code (at least something which is equivalent). Code as posted, Person class is useless, meaning you can't create instance of it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel :| Indeed, I must've tested something else, not sure how's this possible because I ctrl-c ctr-v it :0 Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is really strange (and will crash), but to fill the test for this case exactly:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPersonTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        Person p = new Person(0, "", "");      //note the change

        //Act
        Person result = p.GetPerson();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("John", result.FirstName);
        Assert.AreEqual("Dhoe", result.LastName);
    }
}
```

This doesn't make sense, because the `GetPerson` method will return always the same person, regardless of what you pass to the constructor.

Also, as pointed out by [Sriram Sakthivel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2530848/sriram-sakthivel), this code results in `StackoverflowException` anyway :)

Still this a test for your `GetPerson` method as its currently implemented.

Comment: I see my own faults in the code now. Thank you, i understand your point and will try with a better example.

Comment: @KristofferAndersson Consider posting your refined question as a different post and closing/deleting this one, to avoid confusion for the readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the successful creation of objects with:

```
var myPerson = new Person;
Assert.IsInstanceOf(myPerson, typeof(Person));
```

This is always a good first unit test for tesing classes.